# Need to change one little thing in this macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have this macro which does exactly what I want except for one change. I want it to sort by column "M" instead of "A". I've tried changing it manually, but I keep getting errors. I know it's probably a simple fix but I just can't seem to get it. Thanks in advance!

I've tried to change "Field:=1" to Field:="13", but I get "Run-time error '1004' AutoFilter method of range class failed".

Debug then highlights "rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=cell.Value"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim rngFilter As Range, rngUniques As Range
Dim cell As Range


Set rngFilter = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With rngFilter


    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True


    Set rngUniques = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End With


For Each cell In rngUniques


    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)


    rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value


    rngFilter.EntireRow.Copy
    With wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = True


    wbDest.Sheets(1).Name = cell.Value


    wbDest.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
        cell.Value & " " & Format(Date, "mmm_dd_yyyy")

Next cell

rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  I've updated the code so that all you need to do is change sColumn from A to whatever column letter you want:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const sColumn As String = "A"

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim rngFilter As Range, rngUniques As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngFilter = Range(sColumn & "1", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With rngFilter
        .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
        Set rngUniques = Range(sColumn & "2", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With


    For Each cell In rngUniques
        Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value
        rngFilter.EntireRow.Copy
        With wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
        wbDest.Sheets(1).Name = cell.Value
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wbDest.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & cell.Value & " " & Format(Date, "mmm_dd_yyyy")
        wbDest.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next cell

    rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Now I have a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' fail.

Comment: Debug is highlighting "Set rngFilter = Range(sColumn & "1", Range(secolumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))"

Comment: Had a typo, I have updated the answer with the corrected code

Comment: I can't thank you enough,Tiger! It works perfectly. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting this where your debug error is:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=cell.Value
```

Basically, it seemed that your rngFilter variable was restricting your range to Column A and you're trying to filter based on a column that's outside of this range.
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still get the same error. Debugger is highlighting this line now. I'm stumped!